# Hardcoded method, existing only to be overriden in the superclass

Tags: java, design-patterns

Recently I had to work on a class, that had method similar to this one

```
public boolean checkSomeThing() { return true; }
```

This function was used within the body of another private function performing complicated instantiation.   At first I was thinking it could be an easter egg, but then I read the javadoc on the method checkSomething() was saying something like :

"Override this function to change something blabla".

After reading this I realized what was actually going on. It is a very elegant and neat way of giving access to a variable inside a piece of code that cannot be accessed otherwise.

So my question is what is the name of this trick, pattern or whatever it is called ? Is it a good thing to use, when say the class I am building is intended to be extended?

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding override methods a bit?

Comment: Why is that so ? Please elaborate.

Comment: Are you just talking about abstract methods?: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html

Comment: please upload that piece of code which you are talking about.

Comment: @EvdzhanMustafa, this was taken from wikipedia: *language feature that allows a subclass or child class to provide a specific implementation of a method that is already provided by one of its superclasses or parent classes* ~http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_overriding

Comment: I don't know if Java has the concept of "virtual methods" that C# has (maybe by a different name), but this sounds a lot like that.  Create a base class method with a default implementation (one with no side-effects) and expect derived classes to override it to inject their own functionality.

Comment: @EvdzhanMustafa as for is this a good technique;  like all techniques, used sparingly and in the right context then it is very useful.  Over use it, or where it is not necessary and it is just noise.  The disadvantage of it is that the overiding of the method can be obscured to readers of the code during maintenance.

Comment: this breaks http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle so, no, it is not a good idea

Comment: @OliverWatkins is the strategy pattern equally bad then?

Comment: @OliverWatkins: This can be *used* to break Liskov Substitution, but it doesn't *inherently* break it.  As Chris says, any technique should be applied only where it makes sense.  This is a very commonly used pattern to provide extensibility to derived classes.  Otherwise those classes would need to override considerably more logic and replicate the base class' code, which breaks a whole lot of other principles (including Liskov Substitution).

Comment: yes, you are both right. I take what i said back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say you mean "Template method pattern"
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern

And maybe one suggestion:
If every subclass has to override the method, then it should be abstract.